# jQuery show hide DIV

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm attempting to use jquery to show / hide code snippets on my webpage. Show / hide is controlled through the button clicks. Below is an example of the code that I will use

My questions are

1) How do I repeat this for many code snippets ? at the moment clicking show hide, targets ALL the code snippets on my page

2) Is it possible to hide the code snippet by default, ie when the page loads the code is hidden and create a smooth transition effect?

```
 <button class ="hide button-success">Hide</button>
 <button class= "show button-warning">Show</button>

 <div class ="code">
  <script type="text/javascript"></script>
 </div>




<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hide").click(function(){
    $(".code").hide();
});
    $(".show").click(function(){
    $(".code").show();
    });
});
</script>
```

I Appreciate your help

Comment: If you want to repeat this function, you need $(this) code, to ensure only the current element is take into action. If possible can you post the example code of `many code snippets` that you talking about

Answer (score 1):

Here are the answers to your questions:

1)Your code will correctly for hiding many code snippets having **class** 'code'.

2) On the page load you can initiate hide button **click()** to hide all snippets.For giving a hide transition,just pass the delay time in hide function like `hide(1000);`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hide").click(function(){
        $(".code").hide(1000);
    });
   $(".show").click(function(){
        $(".code").show(1000);
    });
  $(".hide").click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class ="hide button-success">Hide</button>
 <button class= "show button-warning">Show</button>

 <div class ="code">
   Code 1
  <script type="text/javascript"></script>
 </div>
 <div class ="code">
      Code 2
  <script type="text/javascript"></script>
 </div>
 <div class ="code">
      Code 3
  <script type="text/javascript"></script>
 </div>
 <div class ="code">
      Code 4
  <script type="text/javascript"></script>
 </div>
 <div class ="code">
      Code 5
  <script type="text/javascript"></script>
 </div>
```